# .htaccess 301 redirect all pages but the homepage

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to 301 redirect oldsite.com to newsite.com
I want to redirect all pages to the same URLs on the new site, except the homepage. Only the homepage will go to a separate page.

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.siteb.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So what I am trying to do is this:

> oldsite.com/article1 should go to newsite.com/article1
>
> oldsite.com/article2 should go to newsite.com/article2

and so on

However I want the

> homepage oldsite.com to go to newsite.com/old-site

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try with below we are using separate condition and rule for root url and other directories url.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^/]+).com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newsite.com/%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is to redirect all requests except home page so try this at the main root `.htaccess` :

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$  http://www.newsite.com/$1 [L,R=302]
```

Then to redirect homepage to spacific page so add this line :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://www.newsite.com/old-site [L,R=302]
```

Both like this :

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$  http://www.newsite.com/$1 [L,R=302]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://www.newsite.com/old-site [L,R=302]
```

This regex `^(.+)$` will catch every request except `/` then the other regex `^(.*)$` will catch the request to homepage `/` but according to home page you assigned you could except it before the first request like this , considering `index`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index  
RewriteRule ^(.+)$  http://www.newsite.com/$1 [L,R=302]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://www.newsite.com/old-site [L,R=302]
```

If there are query strings you could just put these rules :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://www.newsite.com/old-site [L,R=302]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$  http://www.newsite.com/$1 [L,R=302]
```

So , if there is no query string only with homepage otherwise redirect as is.

**Note:**  if every thing goes Ok , change `302` to `301` to get permanent redirection & make sure you empty browser cache before testing